# Is there any recovered data for covid-19 after August 4th, 2021?

Tags: uses-of-open-data, covid19

I'm searching for the recovered data after that day for any country for my SIR model fitting with python. But I cannot find any recovered data except for CSSE data, there is a data for recovered population but not after August 4th 2021.

Or is it the case that They do not collect the data because it's kind of not essential information? because by period about 10-12 days, we can just predict the recovered population? I mean I'm wonder the reason cannot find an single data for recovered is whether there is no data or my poor searching

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with the recovered measurement is that the definition/concept is almost entirely separate from how it is calculated. It is very difficult for researchers/contact tracers to get follow-up information from confirmed infected after the initial exposure. As a result, many agencies will simply calculate the measurement for the actively infected population and recovered population as being within 45 days of a positive PCR and 45 days or more since a positive PCR respectively. Given the many issues with the recovered measurement, I am not surprised to see many reporting agencies deprecating that indicator.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Additionally you said agencies calculate the recovered population with the number 45(days), is it meaning from confirmed population I, they calculate recovered population R as R(t+1) - R(t) = I/45? Where T is the period of infectious T = 1/45. I'm asking this for my SIR model calculation actually.